# How to design software for blind people to create grids with one sound per square on Android

Tags: android, accessibility, grid, sound, sound-effects

I have gone through the help center issues and it does not seem to me like my question is too subjective.

I want to develop apps that are tailored specifically for blind people to reason about their touchscreens and help them make out how they could conceive of user experience scenarios on those touchscreens.

For example, they may want to design an app to help them with 3D space and orienteering navigation, or an app that has a layout that responds to touch as desired (that does not rely on vision, of course).

I have searched, but couldn't find anything related to what I am about to ask.

....

Here is the gist of the question.

I want a user using Android TalkBack (an accessibility feature for blindness) to activate an app (open it up, and interact with it via the fingers), in the following manner:

- the user must be able to configure a grid, where touching each part of the grid produces a different sound

What would be the right way and what would be the wrong way to do this?

I thought I could:

Have the user tap with two fingers to create a new map, or with three fingers to save the map to a list.

When a new map is created, the user specifies the grid dimensions, perhaps using the keyboard or braille input, for inputting numbers.

Have the user triple tap to switch cyclically between

- edit: touching and releasing fills in the given grid square with a sound (editing the palette that contains sounds)
- delete: same as edit, but touching and releasing gets rid of the sound
- swipe left to go up the pitch, swipe right to go down the pitch, in an octave

Once the map is saved to a list, the user can select a palette-like sound map to interact with where moving the finger produces different sounds

- hovering with the finger while editing plays the sound in the given date square. Some frame to the side of the grid is empty, so a user in delete mode can drag the finger there, and release it without deleting the sound. Hovering in delete mode plays the grid sounds, as in edit mode.
  ....

However, these would be app-specific swipes, that could go in conflict with TalkBack built-in standard swipes.

So how to get the design right without going in conflict with TalkBack.

I have shared my thoughts, I hope my post is accepted and I get some answers. I have followed help center guidelines.

Thanks.

Please migrate my post to Android stack exchange or software recommendations stack exchange if more appropriate on one of these sites.

I hope I have understood what this UX site is about, and what questions it can host.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a tough question. Have you managed to make some progress with this project that you are able to share? Perhaps it will be easier to provide some feedback, as this question seems to require specialist experience.